# To include an content(url) into a jsp

Tags: java, spring, jspx

I need to include all the contents in a particular url in the index.jsp file.

```
http://hostname:9090/dts/flows?page=1&size=10
```

I am using tiles framework.

index.jsp

```
<div xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:page="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:table="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" version="2.0">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <spring:message var="app_name" code="application_name" htmlEscape="false" />
  <spring:message var="title" code="welcome_titlepane" arguments="${app_name}" htmlEscape="false" />
  <util:panel id="title" title="${title}">
    <h3>
      <spring:message code="welcome_h3" arguments="${app_name}" />
    </h3>
    <p>
      <spring:message code="welcome_text" />
    </p>
  </util:panel>
</div>
```

I could see the include directive as `<%@include file="included.jsp" %>`

But I need to add the contents of the url `'http://hostname:9090/dts/flows?page=1&size=10'` into the index.jspx

Can anyone please tell how to fix this?

Comment: retaged, jspx instead of jsp, see http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages for details

Answer (score 3):

Use the JSTL's [`<c:import>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) tag:

> Retrieves an absolute or relative URL and exposes its contents to either the page, a String in 'var', or a Reader in 'varReader'.